# fillna not working in pandas for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, nan

i asigned TEMPERATURE column of NaN value to be zero but not working properly all other columns working properly but this is not s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4xQI.png)

expecting to be temperature column nan values to  be 0 but not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruSw7.png)

Comment: Try this:  `hf.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

Comment: Please edit the question and and provide a useful, descriptive text for the links.

Answer (score 0):

You set the value for the "TEMPERATURE" key (column in DataFrame) in as string `'0'` instead of numeric value `0`. The following will fill the `np.NaN` values in the "TEMPERATURE" column with `0`:

```py
new1 = hf.fillna({"TEMPERATURE": 0, "WIND SPEED": 0, "EVENT": "no event"})
```